# MimeUtility.decode() doesn't work for every encoded text

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, mime, decoding

I am working o a mail application and I have some troubles with decoding mime encoded text. I am using MimeUtility.decode() but it doesn't for every encoded text. Some texts are decoded properly but others couldn't.

These encoded text which can't be decoded especially have utf-8 and iso-8859-9 encoding type.

How I can solve this issue??

This is the code I used for decoding

```
MimeUtility.decodeText(text);
```

These are example of failing text:

[image: Failing Text 1]

[image: Failing Text 2]

Comment: Show us your code an the failing text.

Comment: I added to first message

Comment: Can we guess that the problem is actually the [RFC2047](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc2047) encoding and that the strings which succeed are not encoded like this?

Comment: Why do you use images? Please copy/paste the text instead. Are these two different examples or both part of the same header?

Comment: Actually the string in the second image is nonstandard. `ule=20` should be `ule_` and the closing delimiter `?=` should be adjacent to whitespace (so maybe `ule_Eser?=` instead of `ule=20?=Eser`).

Comment: I solved it and added solution below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

******Solution******* (Thanks to @user_xtech007)

I solve this with problem with decoding encoded parts by splitting multiple encoded parts with regex .

Here is the codes of method I using

```
private final String ENCODED_PART_REGEX_PATTERN="=\\?([^?]+)\\?([^?]+)\\?([^?]+)\\?=";

private String decode(String s)
{
    Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(ENCODED_PART_REGEX_PATTERN);

    Matcher m=pattern.matcher(s);

    ArrayList<String> encodedParts=new ArrayList<String>();

    while(m.find())
    {
        encodedParts.add(m.group(0));

    }

    if(encodedParts.size()>0)
    {
        try
        {
            for(String encoded:encodedParts)
            {
                s=s.replace(encoded, MimeUtility.decodeText(encoded));
            }

            return s;

        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return s;
        }
    }
    else
        return s;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

convert the string you receive into byte array and then use this to decode utf-8 text

```
 String s2 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

first convert the ISO-8859-1 text into bye array then convert it to string

```
 byte[] b2 = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

For getting the encoded string from the uri , you can use Regex

Comment: Please do include the text version so that i can try that out

Comment: I think you are processing the entire text you just need to process the a part of the text from the image

Comment: Your way is working but is there any quick way to get encoded part from whole text?

Answer (score 3):

You can also decode this string by putting

```
System.setProperty("mail.mime.decodetext.strict", "false");
```

Before you use `MimeUtility.decodeText(text);`

This will ensure that also "inner words" get decoded:

> The *mail.mime.decodetext.strict* property controls decoding of MIME
>   encoded words. The MIME spec requires that encoded words start at the
>   beginning of a whitespace separated word. Some mailers incorrectly
>   include encoded words in the middle of a word. If the
>   mail.mime.decodetext.strict System property is set to "false", an
>   attempt will be made to decode these illegal encoded words. The
>   default is true.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html